# I get null exception error in JLabel

Tags: java, jlabel

I have created a login form and a clock, i have set the clock to run on jlabel and when i try to run the program it gives me an error saying,
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at project.jf_login_form$2.run(jf_login_form.java:125)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first call `call()` and then `JL_clock = new JLabel("hello");` So you first call `JL_clock.setText("Time "+hour+":"+minuite+":"+second+"    Date "+day+"/"+month+"/"+year);` before initializing the object.

Possible solution:

```
clock();

JL_username = new JLabel("Username:");
JL_pass = new JLabel("Password:");
JL_clock = new JLabel("hello");
```

Should be replaced with

```
JL_username = new JLabel("Username:");
JL_pass = new JLabel("Password:");
JL_clock = new JLabel("hello");
clock();
```